# using HAVING with another tables record COUNT

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to count row numbers on an another table and use HAVING to select only rows greater than 0.

```
SELECT COUNT(t3.ID),t1.ID,t2.sell,t1.date
FROM `album` t1 
INNER JOIN `members` t2 ON t2.aID = t1.ID 
INNER JOIN `table` t3 ON t3.rID = t1.ID 
WHERE t1.date <= '$dt' AND t2.sell = '1'
ORDER BY t1.date DESC
HAVING COUNT(t3.ID) > 0
```

It doesnt work. where am i wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: didn't you missed the group by clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` clause so that MySQL knows how to group the data when you're using aggregate functions such as `COUNT`.

```
SELECT COUNT(t3.ID),t1.ID,t2.sell,t1.date
FROM `album` t1 
INNER JOIN `members` t2 ON t2.aID = t1.ID 
INNER JOIN `table` t3 ON t3.rID = t1.ID 
WHERE t1.date <= '$dt' AND t2.sell = '1'
GROUP BY t1.ID,t2.sell,t1.date
HAVING COUNT(t3.ID) > 0
ORDER BY t1.date DESC
```

For more information, see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Comment: i get "Invalid use of group function"

Comment: @Ahmet vardar - Actually, you'll need to use `HAVING`... My bad.